# Socket.IO in Nextjs 13.4

Tags: node.js, next.js, websocket, socket.io, next.js13

I have a route which creates a Socket.IO instance:

```
import http, { Server as HttpServer } from "http";
import { Server as NetServer, Socket } from "net";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { Server as SocketIOServer } from "socket.io";

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

type NextApiResponseServerIo = NextApiResponse & {
    socket: Socket & {
        server: NetServer & {
            io: SocketIOServer;
        };
    };
};

// Create a custom HTTP server
const httpServer: HttpServer = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // Handle WebSocket connections here if needed
  });
  
  // Initialize Socket.io with the custom HTTP server
  const io = new SocketIOServer(httpServer, {
    path: "/api/websocket",
    // @ts-ignore
    addTrailingSlash: false,
  });
  
  // Export the custom HTTP server
export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponseServerIo) {
    // Store the Socket.io server in res.socket.server.io
    res.socket.server.io = io;
    // End the response
    res.end();
  };
```

Which is located in my app/api/websocket/route.ts file. I then poll this endpoint from my SocketProvider or from Postman and the result is always the same:

```
error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'server')
```

And neither res.socket, res.socket.server, and io produce anything other than `undefined`.

I've read that Socket.IO is [broken in Next 13](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48422)

But I've tried using the old pages/api/websocket.ts way and it doesn't work. Next doesn't even find the file, returning 404 on all requests.

So is the only way to implement Socket.IO in Next 13.4 to create a separate node server running Socket.IO?